# Find character sequence at specific position in string

Tags: sql, ms-access

I need to use SQL to find a sequence of characters at a specific position in a string.

Example:
atcgggatgccatg

I need to find 'atg' starting at character 7 or at character 7-9, either way would work. I don't want to find the 'atg' at the end of the string. I know about LIKE but couldn't find how to use it for a specific position.

Thank you

Comment: Mid : https://support.office.com/en-sg/article/Mid-Function-427e6895-822c-44ee-b34a-564a28f2532c

Comment: If it was SQL Server, you could use `PATINDEX`. Because it is Access, would `InStr` work? You could test for the index of the pattern and do something if that index is in the right range.

Answer (score 0):

In MS Access, you *could* write this as:

```
where col like '???????atg*' or
      col like '????????atg*' or
      col like '?????????atg*'
```

However, if you interested in this type of comparison, you might consider using a database that supports regular expressions.

Answer (score -1):

If you have a look at [this page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179859.aspx) you'll find that LIKE is entirely capable of doing what you want.  To find something at, for example, a 3 char offset you can use something like this

```
SELECT * FROM SomeTable WHERE [InterestingField] LIKE '___FOO%'
```

The '_' (underscore) is a place marker for any char.  Having 3 "any char" markers in the pattern, with a trailing '%', means that the above SQL will match anything with FOO starting from the fourth char, and then anything else (including nothing).

To look for something 7 chars in, use 7 underscores.

Let me know ifthis isn't quite clear.

EDIT:  I quoted SQL Server stuff, not Access.  Swap in '?' where I have '_', use '*' instead of '%', and check out [this link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb208897(v=office.12).aspx) instead.

Revised query:

```
SELECT * FROM SomeTable WHERE [InterestingField] LIKE '???FOO*'
```

Comment: This is very helpful. Is there any alternatives for the underscores? I ask because the strings will be at least 50 characters long.

Comment: Not that I am aware of, not using LIKE.  There are other options - a commenter on the original post mentions Mid.  I would recommend sticking with LIKE, as it will make your (almost inevitable) transition to SQL Server smoother.